# Spring Java Mail gmail smtp not working in Ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, smtp, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I am just sending the email to users via gmail account. Everything works fine in my development environment (windows 7), but when i move to production ubuntu , then its throwing the following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
at com.product.mailservice.MailServiceImpl.sendMail(MailServiceImpl.java:90)
```

Here is my configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="javaMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="password" value="xxxxxxx"></property>
    <property name="username" value="xxxxxx@gmail.com"></property>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.gmail.com</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.port">465</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.user">xxxxxx@gmail.com</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.password">xxxxxxx</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="from">
        <value>xxxxxx@gmail.com</value>
    </property>
    <property name="subject">
        <value>Password Notification</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="mailService" class="com.product.mailservice.MailServiceImpl">
    <property name="javaMailSender" ref="javaMailSender" />
    <property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage" />
</bean>
```

Update. Here is the debug information

DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\javamail.providers (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false

Comment: Please set <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop> and paste the result, also more lines with exception should be helpful.

Comment: Also, you can [get rid of all the socket factory settings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: But i am new to all these, here is a stupid question, how can i redirect the console output to file in the ubutu production env after turn on mail.debug to true ?

Comment: Hello i added the debug information. Please help